# Intermittent login problems (LDAP timeout?) with ejabberd

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ejabberd

We're running ejabberd 17.07 on an Ubuntu 17.10 VM, and authenticating against an Active Directory on Windows Server 2012 R2.

This *mostly* works, but several times a day, logging in fails. It appears ejabberd runs into a timeout trying to look up information from the LDAP server. Restarting the daemon like so:

```
sudo ejabberdctl restart
```

...obviously kicks everyone out, but afterwards, logging in immediately works again.

I see no apparent related logs on the Windows end (I've looked in the Security and Directory Service logs), suggesting authentication wasn't actually attempd. However, on the ejabberd side, logs like this one sometimes show up:

```
2018-04-30 13:08:05.560 [error] <0.587.0>@eldap_pool:do_request:75 LDAP request failed: timed out
```

And when relaunching the server, this one:

```
2018-04-30 14:58:35.524 [error] <0.793.0>@eldap_pool:do_request:77 LDAP request failed: eldap:search([[{base,<<"ou=Mitarbeiter,dc=…,dc=local">>},{filter,{and,[{equalityMatch,{'AttributeValueAssertion',<<"objectCategory">>,<<"group">>}},{equalityMatch,{'AttributeValueAssertion',<<"cn">>,<<"Alle Mitarbeiter">>}}]}},{timeout,5},{deref_aliases,never},{attributes,[<<"sAMAccountName">>]}]])
Reason: {shutdown,{gen_fsm,sync_send_event,[<0.462.0>,{search,{eldap_search,wholeSubtree,<<"ou=Mitarbeiter,dc=trenz,dc=local">>,{and,[{equalityMatch,{'AttributeValueAssertion',<<"objectCategory">>,<<"group">>}},{equalityMatch,{'AttributeValueAssertion',<<"cn">>,<<"Alle Mitarbeiter">>}}]},0,[<<"sAMAccountName">>],false,neverDerefAliases,5}},110500]}}
```

Notice the "reason: shutdown" part.

Cursory searches suggest this is related to TCP keepalive settings, namely: it appears ejabberd expects the LDAP connection to be left open, whereas Active Directory (silently) expects the request to be a single transaction. Is my understanding of this roughly correct?

If so, short of patching the ejabberd binary like suggested [here](http://lists.jabber.ru/pipermail/ejabberd/2006-September/002167.html) and in other places, what can I do?

(I've also tried, to no avail, to tweak keepalive settings on the Linux machine.)

Comment: Do you have some firewall between ejabberdctl  and AD?

Comment: Nope! They're both in the same subnet. The connection part of the config section looks like:

auth_method: ldap

ldap_servers:
  - "192.168.42.2"

ldap_encrypt: none
ldap_port: 389

Comment: had you seen this: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/788? I guess so because you mention tweaking the keepalive settings, just making sure. Also this: https://www.ejabberd.im/node/4590/index.html

Comment: I have, and like I said, I tried tweaking keepalive settings as suggested in there, but I feel like I don’t have enough knowledge to track this down further (and the consensus in that issue appears to be that ejabberd’s behavior is flawed). ejabberd’s logs aren’t helpful, and Windows’s log doesn’t seem to acknowledge any attempts at all. I could try tcpick as suggested in there, but I don’t ultimately see how that would help beyond getting more confirmation that ejabberd is trying to send data to a dead connection. :(

Comment: (I ended up solving this by writing a dead-simple C# application that is called as an authentication provider. Gives me more logging, and the overhead of calling an external process doesn't really matter if it's just for auth.)